# Максимальные длины непрерывных последовательностей символов в строке

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я написал функцию, которая по входящей строке возвращает словарь, где ключами являются символы строки, а значениями - максимальные длины непрерывных последовательностей этих символов в нашей строке (табуляции, пробелы и переносы строки тоже считаются символами).

То есть:

```
Ввод: '5555aa54c  '
Вывод: {'c': 1, '5': 4, 'a': 2, ' ': 2}
```

Функция выглядит вот так:

```
def maxDict(str):
    count = 1
    md = {str[-1] : 1}
    n = len(str)
    for i in range(n-1):
        if str[i] == str[i + 1]:
            count += 1
            md[str[i]] = max(md.get(str[i], 0), count)
        else:
            count = 1
            md[str[i+1]] = md.get(str[i+1], 1)
    return md
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить проще ?

Пробовал через:

```
for i in range(1, n):
    if str[i - 1] == str[i]:
```

получилось то же самое ((

PS я пробовал гуглить, но там везде нужно только один общий максимум вывести, а у меня для каждого символа свой, а значит без словаря не обойтись.

Comment: Решения gil9red и finally иногда выдают неверный ответ, так что их пока не рассматриваем. Решение Andrei Odegov работает хорошо, но вот написать такое на собеседовании на бумажке (как это и надо было сделать мне) без доступа к компьютеру - будет непросто. Мне же было интересно узнать о существовании альтернативного решения, которое проще, эффективнее по времени и памяти, лаконичнее, но не сложнее с точки зрения восприятия.

Comment: Python не мой язык, но в целом, то, что написано в вопросе мне скорее нравится в качестве решения на собеседовании. За одним исключением - я не очень понял, зачем в случае равенства символов мы обновляем Dictionary, там достаточно пересчитать count.

Comment: @luckman представь, что строка состоит из всех одинаковых символов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример с использованием [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

text = '5555aa54c  '
items = dict(sorted((k, len(list(v))) for k, v in groupby(text)))
print(items)
# {' ': 2, '4': 1, '5': 4, 'a': 2, 'c': 1}
```

---

Как это работает:

- Выражение с `(k, len(list(v))) for k, v in groupby(text)` вернет список кортежей, где первым элементом будет символ, а вторым его количество. Тут `v` вернет генератор, но т.к. генератор не знает сколько у него элементов нужно его преобразовать в список через `list`, а уже у списка можно запросить количество через `len`.

  ```
  [('5', 4), ('a', 2), ('5', 1), ('4', 1), ('c', 1), (' ', 2)]
  ```
- Функция `sorted` упорядочит элементы с одинаковым символом по их количеству. Без сортировки третий шаг неправильно заполнит словарь, например для символа `'5'` (`('5', 4)`, `('5', 1)`) в словарь попадет значение `1`, т.к. предыдущее значение 4 будет затерто

  ```
  [(' ', 2), ('4', 1), ('5', 1), ('5', 4), ('a', 2), ('c', 1)]
  ```
- Самое приятное -- составление словаря по списку из элементов-пар

  ```
  {' ': 2, '4': 1, '5': 4, 'a': 2, 'c': 1}
  ```

Comment: Ваш код работает неправильно для некоторых случаев. К примеру ввод '5555aa54cс' дает вывод {'4': 1, '5': 4, 'a': 2, 'c': 1, 'с': 1}, а должно быть {'4': 1, '5': 4, 'a': 2, 'c': 2}.

Comment: @University, `print([ord(x) for x in 'cс'])  # [99, 1089]` -- одна c русская, другая английская :)

Comment: упс, прошу прощения )) Вы правы ) Ваше решение прекрасно !)

Comment: @University, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте с помощью регулярного выражения:

```py
import re

def maxDict(s):
  d = dict()
  for m in re.finditer(r'(?s)(.)\1*', s):
    c = m.group(1)
    l = len(m.group(0))
    if l > d.get(c, 0):
      d[c] = l
  return d

print(maxDict('''
5555aa45  \n\t



\n
'''))
```

**Вывод:**

```
{' ': 2, '\n': 6, '4': 1, 'a': 2, '5': 4, '\t': 1}
```

Демо на [Rextester](https://rextester.com/KBZ74694).

Comment: if l > d.get(c, 0):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: и даже если так, вернет что то вроде этого {'5': '5555', 'a': 'aa', '4': '4', 'c': 'c'}, а надо {'c': 1, '5': 4, 'a': 2, ' ': 2}

Comment: Оформление на планшете даже такого небольшого фрагмента превращается в какую-то войну

Comment: и как это понять?

Comment: ну еще бы, писать код не за машиной - конский труд)

Answer (score 1):

```py
def mx(stroke):
    md, count, stroke = {i: 1 for i in stroke}, 1, stroke + '^'
    for i in range(len(stroke) - 1):
        if stroke[i] == stroke[i + 1]:
            count += 1
        else:
            md[stroke[i]] = count if count > md[stroke[i]] else md[stroke[i]]
            count = 1
    return md
```

Comment: Ваш код работает неправильно для некоторых случаев. К примеру ввод '^^5555^^^' дает вывод {'^': 2, '5': 4}, а должно быть {'^': 3, '5': 4}.

Comment: замените крышечку на любой символ, который не используется в строках

Comment: Так не пойдет ))) Решение должно работать для любого набора символов.